# CSS Tranisitions and Transforms

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm currently working on a project that needs Windows 10 tiles/blocks like animation ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Q08.png)).

Each of the tile/block has the following structure.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="block-1">
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div class="block-2">
      <p>some other text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to achieve an animation such that, `block-1` should cover up the entire space of `wrapper` initially. After 10 seconds, `block-2` should slide from the bottom of `wrapper` and push `block-1` out of the `wrapper`. Again after a gap of 10seconds, `block-1` should slide from the top of `wrapper`and push `block-2` out of the `wrapper`. This should carry on for every 10seconds.

During the animation, blocks should not overlap each other but push each other while occupying `wrapper`.(just like Windows 10 tile animation.)

The animation should have a neat transition. I tried using CSS Transforms, but not able to achieve it perfectly.

If someone could achieve this, it would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threw together an example of how you'd accomplish this based on your HTML in about 15 minutes, using jQuery and CSS transitions.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```js
function slide() {
  var transitionPause = 3000;

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.wrapper').each(function() {
      $(this).find('.slider').toggleClass('active');
      slide();
    });
  }, transitionPause);
}

slide();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  height: 200%;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.slider.active {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.block {
  height: 50%;
}


/* styles unrelated to the animation: */

.block-1 { background: pink; }
.block-2 { background: teal; }

p {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="block block-1">
      <p>Block 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block block-2">
      <p>Block 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon Uleis .
One thing I forgot to mention was that, **Block 2** should slide from bottom and **Block 1** should slide from top.

Comment: @VinodhK Gotcha - that's actually way easier. I've modified my demo to have that functionality.

Comment: Thanks again for a quick response! This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you @Jon Uleis